# For lock-free programming, is boost::lockfree:: a more feasible option than C++ atomics?

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free, stdatomic

I'm wondering if making threaded code lock-free is better done using `boost::lockfree`. Really, I don't want to introduce anything other than standard C++ into the code. Since `boost::lockfree::` already includes data structures it might be worth implementing lock-free threading using Boost.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: You should check [std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free) and [std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free) for the types you want to use.

Comment: So you are asking whether you should use a high-quality library or writing your own lock-free algorithms which are notoriously hard to implement correctly?

Comment: Not sure the questions in the title really makes sense. If C++11 atomics are available and boost not configured otherwise I would expect `boost::lock_free` to build on `std::atomic`.

Comment: I didn't consider any alternatives. Using a lock-free library that's built on std::atomics would fit the requirement. If boost::lockfree will use std::atomics then there's no issue.

Comment: I wasn't sure about boost::lock_free using std::atomics underneath the hood, but it make sense. In any case I definitely wouldn't start a lock-free data structure project.